# Add and remove rows in a form with unique id's that returns an object as an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, dom

I already have my own solution for this problem, but then I don't know if I'm using the best techniques/practices to solve this particular scenario, which involves removing and adding DOM elements with unique id's.

I have just used jQuery, the requirements where only a button to add any amount of rows, once another row is added be able to delete that row too, the first row is always mandatory, here is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
        <head>
                <meta charset="utf-8"> <title>Simple form</title>
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
                <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
                <style type="text/css">
                  label{
                      display:  block;
                  }
                </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div class="container"> 
                <div class="row inputRows"> 
                    <div class="col-sm-12" id="newRow-1"> 
                        <label>Some label over input</label>
                        <input type="text" name="txt">                        
                    </div>                    
                </div>  
                <div class="row"> 
                    <div class="col-sm-12"> 
                        <button id="addRow"><span class="fa fa-plus"></span> Add </button>
                        <button id="viewInfo"><span class="fa fa-plus"></span> Info </button>
                    </div>          
                </div>                      
                <div class="row"> 
                    <div class="col-sm-12">     
                      <p id="result">
                          
                      </p>
                    </div>          
                </div>                      
            </div>
         
          <script src="https://npmcdn.com/tether@1.2.4/dist/js/tether.min.js"></script>
          <script
          src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
          integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
          crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
          <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript">
                $('.inputRows').on('click', 'button' ,function(){
                    $(this).parent().remove();
                });    

                $('#addRow').click(function(){
                    var $newRow = $('div[id^="newRow"]:first').clone(),
                    newId = Number($('div[id^="newRow"]:last').attr('id').split('-')[1]) + 1;                
                    $newRow.append('<button><span class="fa fa-trash-o"></span></button>');
                    $newRow.find('input').val('');
                    $newRow.attr('id','newRow-' + newId);
                    $('.inputRows').append($newRow);
                });


                $('#viewInfo').click(function(){                            
                    $('#result').text(JSON.stringify(objectifyForm($('div[id^="newRow"]'))));
                });

                function objectifyForm(formArray) {
                  var resultArray = {},
                      inputValue = '';
                  for (var i = 0; i < formArray.length; i++){ 
                    inputValue = $(formArray[i]).find('input').val();
                    if(inputValue){
                      resultArray[$(formArray[i]).attr('id')] = inputValue;  
                    }        
                  }      
                  return resultArray;
                }            
          </script>

        </body>
</html>
```

So the code works, the only problem I see is that the numeration of the id's, can sometimes be 1,5,8,7,6,12 depending on which ones you delete, but then it's fine because in the end, it doesn't even matter (joke, RIP Chester, but kind of true). My main concern or question is, is there any other way of achieving this more efficiently using jQuery? Am I doing something wrong by cloning the first element multiple times? If you can share some knowledge on DOM manipulation that would be great.

Thanks in advance,
Leo.

Comment: you need to create only single remove icon and on click of it remove from last added row to the first.

Comment: That's a good one, but then the requirements were that each new row should have a delete button.

Comment: then what you have is right